# New KLX230 not fully accelerating

Tags: motorcycle, acceleration, kawasaki, clutch-plate

When fully engaging the throttle, the engine starts making an underwater "wompwompwomp" sound and ceases to accelerate further. I'm seeing heavier people than me get their 230's to over 70mph on flat ground, while mine barely reaches 60 going down hill.

Tl;dr acceleration seems weak. Plug isn't fouled, filter is clean. Upon inspection from a mechanic I was told the clutch plates likely needed to be replaced. It could take 2 weeks for them to fix it, and since I've already put 400 miles on the bike I'm not sure if they will agree to pay for the repairs. (Even though it was running like this off the lot).

Considering swapping the plates myself if it's safe and affordable.

Comment: Is this the KLX230, KLX230R, or KLS230S? According to [this website](https://motocrosshideout.com/kawasaki-klx-230/), the KLX230R top speed is 60mph, while the KLX230 is 78mph. Also, you say this is brand new? Isn't there a break-in period for the bike? If so, you might want to wait until you've got it broke-in properly before you start testing the top speed or Kaw my void your warranty for you.

Comment: Klx230 sm. I’ve got about 500 miles on it. Will the engine refuse to hit max power before break in is complete?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it on your bike. I know cars like the Chevrolet Corvette has a built-in break-in period where performance is curtailed until it gets past a certain spot. The reason I was talking about break-in is due to warranty. I know other bikes (I'm more familiar with sport bikes) require a very easy break-in or it will void it. I think is to help keep people from doing stupid things on a brand new bike and expecting the manufacturer to cover it. If I were you, I'd take it back to where you bought it and tell them you're having issues.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: Is this a "new" bike or a "new to you" bike? If it's a "new, off the lot" kinda bike, make them fix it under warranty. Your clutch should not be going out (or have gone out) in only 400 miles. That's bonkers.

Comment: Brand new. The dealer says they don't cover this but hopefully Kawasaki does.